# Extract multiple numbers within parentheses in a text string and sum them in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have order numbers and quantities recorded like this: `# 5397 (5) # 5387 (15)` which means 5 and 15, in total 20. The expected result is `20`.

I already have a custom function implemented in Microsoft Excel VBA:

```
Function SUMAPA(n1 As String)
Longitud = Len(n1)
For i = 1 To Longitud
If Mid(n1, i, 1) = "(" Then
If Mid(n1, i + 2, 1) = ")" Then
Valor = Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 1))
SUMAPA = SUMAPA + Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 1))
ElseIf Mid(n1, i + 3, 1) = ")" Then
Valor = Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 2))
SUMAPA = SUMAPA + Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 2))
ElseIf Mid(n1, i + 4, 1) = ")" Then
Valor = Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 3))
SUMAPA = SUMAPA + Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 3))
ElseIf Mid(n1, i + 5, 1) = ")" Then
Valor = Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 4))
SUMAPA = SUMAPA + Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 4))
ElseIf Mid(n1, i + 6, 1) = ")" Then
Valor = Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 5))
SUMAPA = SUMAPA + Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 5))
ElseIf Mid(n1, i + 7, 1) = ")" Then
Valor = Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 6))
SUMAPA = SUMAPA + Val(Mid(n1, i + 1, 6))
End If
End If
Next i
Debug.Print Valor
Debug.Print SUMAPA

End Function
```

It works well in Excel:

[image: Excel function]

I want to do the same thing in Google Sheets.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Sheets, you can sum the bracketed numbers with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula, without resorting to a macro, like this:

`=sum( split( regexreplace( regexreplace(B1, "#\s*\d+", ""), "[^\d]", " " ), " " ) )`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the formula! but im using order numbers and quantity for example for the product: **apple**  i have two order numbers # 5397 (5) and # 5387 (15) ; so in this example i have two orders that want 5 and 15 apple, in total is 20 apples. so thats why i want that just sum what is inside the brackets or parenthesis but when i use your formula everything sums up.

Comment: Edited the formula to work with data like `# 5397 (5) # 5387 (15)`. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: It works perfectly thank you so much, just one thing, if i dont want to use the # with the order number, how can it be? like for example just 5397 (5) 5387 (15)? or another format can be 5x 5397 15x 5387  in order to avoid the ##

Comment: Please do not ask others to shoot a moving target. Make the _question_ match your real requirements instead of adding requirements gradually in comments. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: Oh Ok sorry! :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have certain type of Google Workspace account you might use the [Macro Converter add-on for Google Sheets](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/macro_converter/383201976440) (see the add-on install page for the current requirements).

If you can't use the add-on or if it doesn't work in your specific case, you have to write an equivalent *custom function* for Google Sheets by using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). You might start by reading [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) then [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

Note: You might find very helpful to learn about regular expressions in JavaScript.

Resources

- [what is the javascript equivalent function for vbscript Mid function? is that substring() or substr()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13946097/1595451)
- [VBA equivalent in JavaScript for use in Google Apps Script for Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27234824/1595451)